# Need a mysql query

Tags: sql, mysql

I have a table  named 'role'

```
id | parent_id | name
---+-----------+--------------------
1  | NULL      | Machine
2  | 3         | Ram
3  | 4         | Cpu
4  | NULL      | Computer
5  | NULL      | Electronic Device
```

I need a  (mysql or postgress sql) query which will  give the possible parents of a particular role.

For example

the possible parent roles of 'Computer' are

```
id | name
---+-------------------
5  | Electronic Device
1  | Machine
```

please help me

Comment: There seems no logical association in the provided data.

Comment: I don't think its possible in single query

Comment: @astander: I think what lintdavis wants to ask is - he has reference to record in same table and he wants to list all chain of references given a particular record in single query

Comment: The provided data is then incomplete.

Comment: uh .. i don't get it .. please check your 'for example'

Answer (score 3):

Use:

```
SELECT t.id,
       t.name
  FROM ROLES t
 WHERE t.parent_id IS NULL
   AND t.name != ?
```

...where `?` is whatever `name` you want to exclude if it's parent_id is null.

Comment: Null is the likely possibility for parent_id, in order to not have a parent.

Comment: There could be hundreds of null entries, of which "computer" is one. Should that then not be a root in itself?

Comment: That's what the 2nd part of the WHERE clause is for.

Comment: That will not ignore all the other (hundreds) of null entries, just in this case *Computer*

Comment: Based on the supplied data, is exactly what the query would return.  The question asks for *possible* parent records.

Answer (score 1):

Ignoring the fact that the data in your given example doesn't match up, I think what you're trying to do is store and fetch hierarchical data in a database, where you end up with a chain of parents and children.

There are several approaches to storing and retrieving this kind of data.  I highly recommend you read this Sitepoint article:  [Storing Hierarchical Data in a Database](http://articles.sitepoint.com/article/hierarchical-data-database/1).

The most common approach is the Adjacency List model, whereby you select the first record, then select it's parent, then select it's parent, etc, until you have the whole chain of records.  This is a read-heavy, write-light approach, and easy to implement.

If you want a fast read approach, the Modified Preorder Tree Traversal (page 2) is an amazing algorithm.  More difficult to implement, but you can select an entire set of children/parent records in a single SELECT.

Answer (score 1):

Based on comments from other users (and maybe a lack of complete data), it seems like a self reference table. So if the data is corrected you can try

```
select r2.* 
from role as r1 inner join 
role as r2 on r1.parent_id=r2.id 
where r1.name='Computer';
```

with data being

```
id | parent_id | name
---+-----------+--------------------
1  | NULL      | Machine
2  | 3         | Ram
3  | 4         | Cpu
4  | 1         | Computer
5  | NULL      | Electronic Device
```