# Recursive function·

Tags: php, function, mysql

```
    4             Computer
    5      6      food1
    6             food2
```

I need to select possible parents.

For example:

1. If we select 'machine' all others can parents
2. If we select 'cpu' then 'ram' and 'cpu' should not be there.
3. If we take 'food2' then 'food2', 'food1' should not be there All others 
   have possibility.

How do I write a (PHP, MySQL recursive) function in a class?
Note: only using a single function.

Comment: Very similar to: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1892493/need-a-mysql-query

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i have the same issue

class test {

```
public static $roleIds;
```

public function  availableParents()
    {
        self::$roleIds = null;

```
    $discardRoleIds = implode(',',$this->unAvailableRoles());

    $parentRoles = Acl_Model_Role::fetchAll("id NOT IN ({$discardRoleIds}) AND isactive = true" );

    return $parentRoles;        
}

/**
 * Getting  not available role id
 * 
 * @author Linto
 * @since 2009-11-25
 * @return Array 
 */
public function unAvailableRoles()
{
    $where = "parent_id = {$this->getId()}"; 

    self::$roleIds[] = $this->getId();       

    $count = Acl_Model_Role::count($where);

    if($count != 0) {
        foreach(Acl_Model_Role::fetchAll($where) as $role){                   
            $role ->unAvailableRoles();                
        }         
    }
    return  self::$roleIds; 

}
```

}

it will work fine, if we use one time

if situation is like this
$role //created object with id 1

$role->availableParents()

$role //created object with id 2
$role->availableParents()

$role //created object with id 3
$role->availableParents()

we will not get correct answer (first lines will change the second model too.)